# VSTO Visio Addin - click once EULA depenency

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, clickonce, eula

I have developed a Click once VSTO Visio Addin using Visual Studio 2019. I want to prompt the user with a standard EULA consent dialog when the setup.exe installer is run. I have found the following, which relates to an older version of Visual Studio:

https://bhrnjica.net/2015/08/31/add-eula-to-clickonce-installation-using-visual-studio-2015/

I would have thought that this was a common requirement, but cannot find anything for more contemporary versions. Any assistance / suggestions would be gratefully received.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Boeryepes yes it works subject to update below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page describes where prerequisites for Visual Studio 2019 need to be located:

https://foxlearn.com/articles/adding-custom-prerequisites-to-visual-studio-setup-project-468.html

Specifically the instructions from the first link can be followed, but the prerequisite needs to be configured under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages
```